# How to pass name from Google maps to a function?

Tags: jquery, meteor, meteor-autoform

I have this autoform inside a template:

```
<div class="map-container">
  {{> googleMap name="exampleMap" options=exampleMapOptions}}
</div>
```

Inside my template.onCreated I have the following function:

```
GoogleMaps.ready('exampleMap', function(map) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: map.options.center,
    map: map.instance
  });
});
```

What I want to do, is to have the name of the map be the same as the document ID, so that a marker is added to each of the maps that are being rendered.

I can easily do `name={{id}}` to have the googleMap name be a unique ID, but how can I do something similar in my script?

Comment: Do you want to have access to the template's data context inside your `onCreated` callback? If this is the case, you could just use `this.data`.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the template context using "this.data" in OnCreated and OnRendered callbacks.

In your case, it goes like this

```
<Template name="example">
{{#autoForm id=formId doc=currentDoc collection=collection type="normal"}}
  {{> googleMap name=currentDoc._id options=exampleMapOptions}}
{{/autoForm}}
</Template>
```

You can pass the data context to template using several ways.

```
Template.example.helpers({
 formId: functions() {
   return this._id
 },
 currentDoc: function() {
  return this 
 }
})
```